# wrap content for numbers

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to use `wrap_content` on `TextView` where I keep only numbers (and coma), but I have noticed that this takes more space than needed (as if reserved space for letters).
Shown here:
[image link http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/3784/wrap.jpg](http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/3784/wrap.jpg)

Current situation - blue lines, desired - gray lines.

If it's not possible to do this with numbers and coma, maybe it is possible only with numbers?

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="sampleText" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/image" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:text="0,00"
                    android:textSize="50dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

For example, MyTextView works as I wrote. The thing is that I want to center vertical my image, but it's not properly centered due to fact MyTextView takes more space than needed.

Comment: Did you check if you have any padding/margin bottom/top ?

Comment: yup, I don't have any padding/margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `android:includeFontPadding` to `false`, it is `true` by default. It will reduce the padding significantly although it does not remove it completely. Be sure to test this on a real device, since it had no effect for me in the layout preview. Set a background color to see the difference.

```
<TextView 
    ...
    android:includeFontPadding="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it using `textView.setTextSize(15dp);`
I am using numbers in textView. I didnt feel it as a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set height and width of the textview as wrap_content.Like,

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: That's the matter - I did this, please read my question properly and see picture.

Comment: If you correctly set wrap_content then there wont be any extra spaces.Can you show me your layout?

Comment: Edited my post, so you can see my layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `TextView:         android:inputType="phone"`

Answer (score 0):

are you using a custom font?  If so, one possibility is that the padding you see is built into the font.

Comment: No, I'm not using custom font.